# Anagram generation - Isnt it kind of subset sum?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, subset-sum

Anagram:

> An anagram is a type of word play, the result of rearranging the
>   letters of a word or phrase to produce a new  word or phrase, using
>   all the original letters exactly once;

Subset Sum problem:

> The problem is this: given a set of integers, is there a non-empty
>   subset whose sum is zero?
>
> For example, given the set { −7, −3, −2, 5, 8}, the answer is yes
>   because the subset { −3, −2, 5} sums to zero. The problem is
>   NP-complete.

Now say we have a dictionary of n words. Now Anagram Generation problem  can be stated as to find a set of words in dictionary(of n words) which use up all letters of the input. So does'nt it becomes a kind of subset sum problem.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd prove that solving anagram finding (not more than polynomial number of times) solves subset sum problem - it would be a revolution in computer science (you'd prove P=NP).

Clearly finding anagrams is polynomial-time problem:

Checking if two records are anagrams of each other is as simple as sorting letters and compare the resulting strings (that is `C*s*log(s)` time, where `s` - number of letters in a record). You'll have at most `n` such checks, where `n` - number of records in a dictionary. So obviously the running time ~ `C*s*log(s)*n` is limited by a polynomial of input size - your input record and dictionary combined.

**EDIT:**

All the above is valid only if the anagram finding problem is defined as finding anagram of the input phrase in a dictionary of possible complete phrases.

While the wording of the anagram finding problem in the original question above...

> Now say we have a dictionary of n words. Now Anagram Generation problem can be stated as to find a set of words in dictionary(of n words) which use up all letters of the input.

...seems to imply something different - e.g. a possibility that some sort of composition of more than one entry in a dictionary is also a valid choice for a possible anagram of the input.

This however seems immediately problematic and unclear because (1) usually phrase is not just sequence of random words (it should make sense as a whole phrase), (2) usually words in a phrase require separators that are also symbols - so it is not clear if the separators (whitespace characters) are required in the input to allow the separate entries in a dictionary and if separators are allowed in a single dictionary entry.

So in my initial answer above I applied a "semantic razor" by interpreting the problem definition the only way it is unambiguous and makes sense as an "anagram finding".

But also we might interpret the authors definition like this:

> Given the dictionary of n letter sequences (separate dictionary entries may contain same sequences) and one target letter sequence - find any subset of the dictionary entries that if concatenated together would be exact rearrangement of the target letter sequence **OR** determine that such subset does not exist.

^^^- Even though this problem no longer really makes perfect sense as an "anagram finding problem" still it is interesting. It is very different problem to what I considered above.

One more thing remains unclear - the alphabet flexibility. To be specific the problem definition must also specify whether set of letters is fixed **OR** it is allowed to redefine it for each new solution of the problem when specifying dictionary and target sequence of said letters. That's important - capabilities and complexity depends on that.

The variant of this problem with the ability to define the alphabet (available number of letters) for each solution individually actually is equivalent to a subset sum problem. That makes it NP-complete.

I can prove the equivalence of our problem to a natural number variant of subset sum problem defined as

> Given the collection (multiset) of natural numbers (repeated numbers allowed) and the target natural number - find any sub-collection that sums exactly to the target number **OR** determine that such sub-collection does not exist.

It is not hard to see that mostly linear number of steps is enough to translate one problem input to another and vice versa. So the solution of one problem translates to exactly one solution of another problem plus mostly linear overhead.

This positive-only variant of subset-sum is equivalent to zero-sum subset-sum variant given by the author (see e.g. [Subset Sum Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)).

Comment: This is true for anagrams of words, but not entirely true if you consider anagrams for phrases, such as "eleven plus two = twelve plus one". (Both were part of the question.)

Comment: @HansOlsson Very good point. You are absolutely right. Now after a brief thinking - off the top of my head - I'm no longer sure that this task that allow phrases isn't NP-hard. And indeed is feels kind of similar to subset sum problem with some possible additional limitations (those limitations require clarification in task description however) and some additional freedom. I'll edit the answer when I have time.

Answer (score 4):

The two problems are similar but are not [isomorphic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/isomorphic).

- In an anagram the order of the letters matters.  In a subset sum, the order does not matter.
- In an anagram, all the letters must be used.  In a subset sum, any subset will do.
- In an anagram, the subgroups must form words taken from a comparatively small dictionary of allowable words (the dictionary).  In a subset sum, the groups are unrestricted (no dictionary of allowable groupings).

Comment: Could the two not be isomorphic and still both be NP-complete given that NP-complete?  Also, I didn't think you could biject an NP-complete approach (without proving P=NP), and therefore I have to wonder if you can even truly determine isomorphism.  I guess merely demonstrating that one function is bijective if an NP-complete problem is assumed to never be bijective would effectively demonstrate the same?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are wrong.

Anagram Generation must be simpler than Subset Sum, because I can devise a trivial O(n) algorithm to solve it (as defined):

```
initialize the list of anagrams to an empty list
iterate the dictionary word by word
    if all the input letters are used in the ith word
        add the word to the list of anagrams

return the list of anagrams
```

Also, anagrams consist of valid words that are *permutations* of the input word (i.e. rearrangements) whereas subsets have no concept of order. They may actually include less elements than the input set (hence *sub* set) but an anagram must always be the same length as the input word.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't NP-Complete because given a single set of letters, the set of anagrams remains identical regardless.

There is always a single mapping that transforms the letters of the input L to a set of anagrams A.  so we can say that f(L) = A for any execution of f.  I believe, if I understand correctly, that this makes the function deterministic.  The order of a Set is irrelevant, so considering a differently ordered solution non-deterministic is invalid, it is also invalid because all entries in a dictionary are unique, and thus can be deterministically ordered.